# Index added but is not applied to queries executed by app

Tags: postgresql, index

### TL;DR

Queries are too slow on one of tables, Added index but no change

### Description:

There is a `channels` table with 1 million records. Displaying it's content in the app takes up to 10s! I checked db monitoring and found out this slow query:

```sql
SELECT "public"."channels"."id",
  "public"."channels"."customer_id",
  "public"."channels"."service_id",
  "public"."channels"."server_id",
  "public"."channels"."name",
  "public"."channels"."title",
  "public"."channels"."description",
  "public"."channels"."image",
  "public"."channels"."password",
  "public"."channels"."options",
  "public"."channels"."time_usage",
  "public"."channels"."time_total",
  "public"."channels"."max_users",
  "public"."channels"."session_duration",
  "public"."channels"."status",
  "public"."channels"."create_time",
  "public"."channels"."update_time",
  "public"."channels"."time_limit",
  "public"."channels"."is_public",
  "public"."channels"."record"
FROM "public"."channels"
WHERE "public"."channels"."customer_id" = $1
ORDER BY "public"."channels"."id" DESC
LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
```

I noticed that here is not any indexes on `customer_id` field and added an index. Now running queries from cli is fast using index But application is still slow! I cehcked monitoring and logged slow queries using `log_min_duration_statement = 5000` and saw that query again:

```
LOG:  duration: 11692.503 ms  execute s561: SELECT "public"."channels"."id", "public"."channels"."customer_id", "publ
ic"."channels"."service_id", "public"."channels"."server_id", "public"."channels"."name", "public"."channels"."title", "public"."channels"."descri
ption", "public"."channels"."image", "public"."channels"."password", "public"."channels"."options", "public"."channels"."time_usage", "public"."ch
annels"."time_total", "public"."channels"."max_users", "public"."channels"."session_duration", "public"."channels"."status", "public"."channels"."create_t
ime", "public"."channels"."update_time", "public"."channels"."time_limit", "public"."channels"."is_public", "public"."channels"."record" FROM "public"."sk
yroom_channels" WHERE "public"."channels"."customer_id" = $1 ORDER BY "public"."channels"."id" DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '360669', $2 = '10', $3 = '0'
```

I tried this query with `customer_id=360669` in the CLI but took just 703ms!
This is the plan:

```
                                                                          QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=177875.56..177875.58 rows=10 width=796) (actual time=658.246..658.249 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=41918
   ->  Sort  (cost=177875.56..177875.62 rows=27 width=796) (actual time=649.842..649.844 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: id DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=41918
         ->  Index Scan using channels_idx on channels  (cost=0.55..177874.97 rows=27 width=796) (actual time=123.116..649.732 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (customer_id = 360669)
               Buffers: shared hit=41915
 Planning Time: 0.729 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.948 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.022 ms, Emission 7.064 ms, Total 9.034 ms
 Execution Time: 703.384 ms
(15 rows)
```

This is table properties:

```
database=# \d channels
                                         Table "public.channels"
      Column      |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id               | integer                |           | not null | nextval('channels_id_seq'::regclass)
 customer_id      | integer                |           | not null | 0
 service_id       | integer                |           | not null |
 server_id        | integer                |           |          |
 name             | character varying(128) |           | not null |
 title            | character varying(128) |           | not null |
 description      | character varying(512) |           |          |
 image            | character varying(255) |           |          |
 password         | character varying(32)  |           |          |
 options          | text                   |           |          |
 time_usage       | bigint                 |           | not null | 0
 time_total       | bigint                 |           | not null | 0
 max_users        | integer                |           |          | 20
 session_duration | integer                |           |          |
 status           | smallint               |           |          | 1
 create_time      | integer                |           |          |
 update_time      | integer                |           |          |
 time_limit       | integer                |           |          |
 is_public        | boolean                |           |          | false
 record           | integer                |           |          | 0
Indexes:
    "channels_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "channels_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name, customer_id)
    "channels_customer_id" btree (customer_id)
    "channels_server_idx" btree (server_id)
    "channels_service_idx" btree (service_id)
```

### Environment

- [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)+[NestJs](https://www.nestjs.com/)
- PostgreSQL 12.12 on ubuntu 20.04
- PGBouncer

### Database Memory

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          123Gi        36Gi       673Mi        30Gi        86Gi        55Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi       4.0Gi          0B
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. You could maybe install the [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html)  module to get that plan automatically.

Comment: Use auto_explain to capture the plan of the slow query coming from the app.  You are assuming it is not using the index, while is probably is using the index, but is just slow because the data is not in cache. But then when you rerun it on the command line, the data is still in cache since the previous run put it there.

Comment: Why would an index scan need to hit 41915 buffers just to read one row?  Your index seems to be massively bloated.  Look for transactions which have been open for a long time that prevent the data from getting cleaned up.